# Get specific XML entries with multiple search queries

Tags: jquery, xml, search, jqtouch

I didn't know how to search for my actual problem getting data from XML for a jQTouch app, so I hope you can help me with it.

Here are the code parts that are working -- in that the correct sum of entries with the keyword in the title are found.

But, the vars aren't shown.
So how do I get the other search query fields into the game?

My XML Base

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programm>
<kurs nr="11165010">
    <nr>11165010</nr>
    <bereich>Bereich 1</bereich>
    <titel>abc</titel>
    <text>Text 1</text>
    <bezirk>Bezirk 1</bezirk>
</kurs>
<kurs nr="11201061">
    <nr>11201061</nr>
    <bereich>Bereich 2</bereich>
    <titel>Xyz</titel>
    <text>Text 2</text>
    <bezirk>Bezirk 2</bezirk>
</kurs>
...
</programm>
```

My HTML

```
<div id="kurs_suche">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Kursprogramm</h1>
        <a href="#home" class="button back"><img alt="home" src="thumbs/home.png" align="absmiddle"/></a>
    </div>
    <form id="search">
        <ul class="rounded">
            <li id="notice">Detail-Kurssuche:</li>
            <li><input name="suche_text" type="text" id="suche_text" placeholder="Suchwort(e)" autofocus/></li>
            <li>
            <select name="suche_bereich" id="suche_bereich">
                <option value="0" selected='selected'>Bereich (optional)</option>
                <option value='Bereich 1'>Bereich 1</option>
                <option value='Bereich 2'>Bereich 2</option>
            </select>
            </li>
            <li>
            <select name="suche_bezirk" id="suche_bezirk">
                <option value="0" selected='selected'>Bezirk (optional)</option>
                <option value='Bezirk 1'>Bezirk 1</option>
                <option value='Bezirk 2'>Bezirk 2</option>
            </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="whiteButton submit">Kurs(e) finden</a>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- KURSE SUCHERGEBNIS -->
<div id="kurs_liste">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Suchergebnis</h1>
        <a href="#home" class="button back">zur&uuml;ck</a>
    </div>
    <div id="kurs_liste_ausgabe">
        <ul class="rounded" id="kurse">
            <li>Kurse werden geladen ...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- KURS ANSICHT -->
<div id="kurs_detail">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Kurs Details</h1>
        <a href="#home" class="button back">zur&uuml;ck</a>
    </div>
    <div id="kurs_details">
        <p>
            Kurs wird geladen ...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#search').submit(function () {
    //grab the notice div so we can manipulate it
    var notice = $('#notice');
    //grab the notice instructions so we can reset
    var noticetxt = notice.html();
    //set notice to searching...
    notice.empty().append('Kurse werden gesucht, bitte warten ...');
    //get the keywords
    var stext = $('#suche_text').val();
    var sbereich = $('#suche_bereich option:selected').val();
    var sbezirk = $('#suche_bezirk option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "kursprogramm.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (data) {
            parseXML(data);
            jQT.goTo('#kurs_liste', 'slideleft');
        }
    });

    function parseXML(data) {
        var pub = "";
        $(data).find('kurs').find("titel:contains('" + stext + "')").each(function () {
            var knr = $(this).find('nr').text();
            var ktitel = $(this).find('titel').text();
            var kbereich = $(this).find('bereich').text();
            var kbezirk = $(this).find('bezirk').text();
            var kvdat = $(this).find('vondatum').text();
            pub += '<li class=\"arrow\"><a href=\"#kurs_detail\" class=\"KursLink slideleft\" id=\"' + knr + '\">' + ktitel + '<br />' + kbezirk + ', ' + kvdat + '</a></li>' + '\n';
        });
        $('#kurse').html(pub);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: The question is not clear.  You seem to be parsing the XML and adding the data to the page.  What's missing or wrong? ...  Also try to [boil it down to a small-self contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: actual the function parseXML seems to find all items which contains stext in the titel, it also writes the correct amount of li tags to the html but the variables are missing (knr, ktitel, ...) - furthermore the selection is only based on the keyword given in stext - but how to include the other selected option from the searchform? i hope i'm now more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Clarified Requirements:

1. Search by any combination of bezirk, bereich, titel text.

The code, below is updated to not require a search string.

~~~
First, beware that `contains()` is case-sensitive!  your users may not appreciate that. ;)

Consider extending jQuery like so:

```js
//--- Extend jQuery with a case-insensitive version of contains().
jQuery.extend (
    jQuery.expr[':'].containsCI = function (a, i, m) {
        var sText   = (a.textContent || a.innerText || "");//-- faster than jQuery(a).text()
        var zRegExp = new RegExp (m[3], 'i');

        //Pro tip.  This allows search on regular expressions, too!
        return zRegExp.test (sText);
    }
);
```

Then code like this should work:
[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2p7cB/6/)

```js
var srchResults;

//--- Are we searching for text?
if (stext == 0  ||  /^\s*$/.test (stext) ) {
    //--- No text search was given.  Case-sensitive is fine, here.
    srchResults = $("kurs", data).find ("bereich:contains('" + sbereich + "'), bezirk:contains('" + sbezirk + "')")
} else {
    //--- text search.  The select boxes will also be filtered, below.
    srchResults = $("kurs", data).find ("titel:containsCI('" + stext + "')")
}

var pub = "";
srchResults.parent ().each (function () {
    //--- "this" is one of the <kurs> nodes that matches the search string.
    var childVals   = {};

    //--- Capture the value of each child node. Note that structure is single-depth.
    $(this).children ().each ( function () {
        //-- Note that nodeName is always returned in all uppercase.
        childVals [this.nodeName]   = $(this).text ();
    } );

    //--- Are we filtering on selectors?
    if (sbezirk  != 0  &&  sbezirk  != childVals.BEZIRK)     return;
    if (sbereich != 0  &&  sbereich != childVals.BEREICH)    return;

    //--- Build the HTML nodes.
    //Note that vondatum is not in the data!
    pub    += '<li class="arrow">'
            +   '<a href="#kurs_detail" class="KursLink slideleft" id="' + childVals.NR + '">'
            +       childVals.TITEL + '<br />' + childVals.BEZIRK + ', ' + childVals.BEREICH
            +   '</a>'
            + '</li>\n';
} );
$('#kurse').html (pub);
```